# Subsetting on all but empty grep returns empty vector

Tags: r, vector, operators, grepl

Suppose I have some character vector, which I'd like to subset to elements that don't match some regular expression. I might use the `-` operator to remove the subset that `grep` matches:

```
> vec <- letters[1:5]
> vec
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> vec[-grep("d", vec)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "e"
```

I'm given back everything except the entries that matched `"d"`. But if I search for a regular expression that isn't found, instead of getting everything back as I would expect, I get nothing back:

```
> vec[-grep("z", vec)]
character(0)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `grep` returns an integer vector, and when there's no match, it returns `integer(0)`.

```
> grep("d", vec)
[1] 4
> grep("z", vec)
integer(0)
```

and the since the `-` operator works elementwise, and `integer(0)` has no elements, the negation doesn't change the integer vector:

```
> -integer(0)
integer(0)
```

so `vec[-grep("z", vec)]` evaluates to `vec[-integer(0)]` which in turn evaluates to `vec[integer(0)]`, which is `character(0)`.

You will get the behavior you expect with `invert = TRUE`:

```
> vec[grep("d", vec, invert = TRUE)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "e"
> vec[grep("z", vec, invert = TRUE)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```